# Connect to network through another computer

Tags: windows, networking, macos

I am using a macbook and a Windows 7 PC. The macbook is wirelessly connected to the same router that the PC is wired to.

Is there a way for my laptop to access the same network drives that the PC has access to?

How can I connect the laptop to the `P:\` network drive that I have access to from the PC?

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows PC open a Command Prompt and give the command "net use" (without the "").
This gives a list op connected network drives, including that P: drive you mentioned.
After the P: you will see something like \\some_server-name\share-name\path
(The path part is optional and may not be there at all.)

On the Mac select "Connect to a network-drive" from the menu. Specify the path as smb://some_server_name/share-name/path
If you are asked for credentials supply the same username/password that you would use on the Windows computer to logon.

This makes the Mac try to connect to the share in the same way as the Windows computer is doing. (And the connection is independent of the Windows computer itself. There is no need to route it via the Windows computer, that would only complicate matters unnecessarily.)

You mentioned restrictions on the Windows computer. If this is a strictly controlled environment this may not work at all, depending on how the environment is set up. If that is the case you probably need to ask the sys-admin responsible for the restrictions whether you are allowed to hook up the Mac and, if yes, how to do it.